# How does Jesque work with Huge Payload?

Tags: background-process, resque, worker

I read about Jesque at https://github.com/gresrun and I would like to understand how does it perform under huge payload. Is the only way of queuing a job to create an instance of Job class and then using a Thread to start off the worker or are there any other approaches? I am a little skeptical about using java.lang.Thread objects like it is done in the example on this link for batch jobs where data payload is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually spawing threads without control is never a good idea.

I would suggest the approach to put your workers in a BlockingQueue and then spawn a *very* limited number of threads (as much as your CPUs, in order to reduce contention) to start off those workers. Once the work has finished, the thread pick up a new worker and start the process again. Once there are no worker in the queue, the threads just hangs on the queue, waiting for new workers.

You can have a look at the [Thread Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)

Comment: Any example of that implementation !?